# Подскажите как PyCharm изменить имя переменой сразу в нескольких местах?

Tags: pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу добавить self. ко все переменным man_calories, но прописывать для каждой это долго, можно ли как то изменить за раз все сразу переменны man_calories?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> (курсор должен быть на переменной)

или `Top Menu -> Refactor -> Rename`

Comment: Shift + f8 не сработал

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения связанных переменных выделите необходимую переменную и нажмите ctrl+shift+f6

Answer (score -1):

Если вы не меняли настроек по умолчанию, то:

1. Найти и заменить в проекте ==> Ctrl + Shift + R
2. Найти и заменить в локальном файле ==> Ctrl + R

Иногда вместо R нужно использовать H или F

Comment: Это можно конечно, у меня есть в файле еще переменная woman_calories и он изменяет ее тоже, а мне этого не нужно

Comment: @Tesla Вы заменяете man_calories на self.man_calories? Если да, то woman_calories не должно затрагиваться)